# jquery function's runtime is slow

Tags: jquery, runtime

this  function working good but it's a little bit slow

**html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><span id="ItemPrice">10</span></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <p><span id="ItemTotal">0</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
function CountItemTotal() {
        $("span#ItemTotal")
            .each(function () {
                $(this).text(
                    +$(this)
                        .closest("tr")
                        .find("#ItemPrice")
                        .text()
                    *
                    +$(this)
                        .closest("tr")
                        .find("#quantity")
                        .val()
                )
                    .fadeOut("fast")
                    .fadeIn("fast");
            });
    }

$("input#quantity").change(function () {
        CountItemTotal();
    });
```

any idea how to increase the runtime of this function ?

" i don't know why i got this message but it says i have to add some extra text cuz most of my post is code anyway never mind this :) "

Comment: Remove the .`.fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast")` from your code.

Comment: @user9263373 is there any other way to do the effect ?

Comment: Not that I know of.  `CountItemTotal()` will apply the effect every time it's changed. Unless there's someone on SO knows how to apply the effect just once, you will have to remove the effect.

Comment: Another way to speed up your code is refactor it by removing `.each()`, `closest()` and `find()`.

Comment: if i removed `.each()`, `closest()` and `find()` the whole code will be useless cuz in the real code there's many rows and i need to find the specific price and total for each row !!

Comment: ... _"the whole code will be useless cuz in the real code there's many rows"_ ... Well you never mentioned that in your post so how was I to know?  Also you're using IDs, so that presumes they will only appear once in the DOM.  As it stands, once you add more rows, then your code is useless unless you change the IDs to classes.

Comment: i know i never mentioned that in my post i didn't say that your solution is wrong i just mentioned in the comment that it wont work in my code just misunderstand :) and about the IDs the whole row repeats for each item so at the end its working good hope you got the right image :)

Comment: Well perhaps then you managed to find a loophole around the way the DOM works by using the `.each()` function to accommodate for repeating IDs. So it's **_interesting_** that you say it works, but if it does work then it's bad practice.  Also, if you change IDs to classes you can remove `each()`.  For example, if you have 100 rows, with `each()` your calculation runs 100 times when it only needs to update the current row it's on.

Comment: can you give me an example how to change IDs to classes **Note that** i'm not advanced with javascript and to clear the image i'm  using this code in .net core app if that make difference

Comment: Yes, I just posted an answer using classes.  Hope this helps!

Comment: i'm gonna test it now and tell you the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your calculation perform better you can make the following changes.

1. Remove the `.fadeOut("fast")` and `.fadeIn("fast")`.
2. Change the `id`s to `class`es since you mentioned you need to repeat the rows more than once.
3. Removed the `each()` so that only the current row gets updated.

See working example below.

```js
function CountItemTotal($this) {
  var tr = $this.closest("tr");
  var ItemTotal = tr.find(".ItemTotal");
  var ItemPrice = tr.find(".ItemPrice");
  var quantity = tr.find(".quantity");

  ItemTotal.text(ItemPrice.text() * quantity.val());
}

$("input.quantity").change(function() {
  CountItemTotal($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p><span class="ItemPrice">10</span></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="quantity" value="1" min="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <p><span class="ItemTotal">0</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p><span class="ItemPrice">10</span></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="quantity" value="1" min="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <p><span class="ItemTotal">0</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p><span class="ItemPrice">10</span></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="quantity" value="1" min="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <p><span class="ItemTotal">0</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p><span class="ItemPrice">10</span></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="quantity" value="1" min="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <p><span class="ItemTotal">0</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well this way working fine and more clear than mine thanks a lot dude for 
your help

Comment: i'm so sorry i have 11 reputation so i can't vote for your answer

Comment: @AhmedMohamed no worries.  Glad it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

just for help i got that

this query gonna apply an effect better that the first one i posted

```
function CountItemTotal($this) {
 var tr = $this.closest("tr");
 var ItemTotal = tr.find(".ItemTotal");
 var ItemPrice = tr.find(".ItemPrice");
 var quantity = tr.find(".quantity");

ItemTotal.fadeOut(function () {
     $(this).text(ItemPrice.text() * quantity.val()).fadeIn();
  });
}

$("input.quantity").change(function() {
   CountItemTotal($(this));
});
```

the element fade out then come in with new value :)